# Compare 2 nested Json Array, Override and merge Json A by Json B

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, express, compare-and-swap

I have 2 json array, need to compare them , if "id" property in Json A match the "id" property in Json B, override the Json A property values with Json B property values

Json A Array:

```
{
"components":[
    {
        "id":"uibuilder:fa10894e44b3460c93912198a99e3629",
        "component":{
            "name":"Hero",
            "properties":{
                "imageUrl":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532298229144-0ec0c57515c7?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2000&q=80",
                "caption1":"New Collection",
                "caption2":"About this collection",
                "buttonText":"Click Me!"
            }
        },
        "componentStyle":{
            "large":{
                "display":"flex",
                "flexDirection":"column",
                "position":"relative",
                "flexShrink":"0",
                "boxSizing":"border-box",
                "marginTop":"20px",
                "minHeight":"20px",
                "minWidth":"20px",
                "overflow":"hidden"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id":"uibuilder:8818c12fe5c94b27b7f7033fec7910b6",
        "component":{
            "name":"Text",
            "properties":{
                "text":"<p>This iss text</p>"
            }
        },
        "componentStyle":{
            "large":{
                "display":"flex",
                "flexDirection":"column",
                "position":"relative",
                "flexShrink":"0",
                "boxSizing":"border-box",
                "marginTop":"20px",
                "minHeight":"20px",
                "minWidth":"20px",
                "overflow":"hidden"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id":"uibuilder:8818c12fe5c94b25c94b23fec033fec7",
        "component":{
            "name":"Text New",
            "properties":{
                "text":"<b>Component heading</b>"
            }
        },
        "componentStyle":{
            "large":{
                "display":"flex",
                "flexDirection":"column",
                "position":"relative",
                "flexShrink":"0",
                "boxSizing":"border-box",
                "marginTop":"10px",
                "minHeight":"10px",
                "minWidth":"10px",
                "overflow":"hidden"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Json B Array

```
{
"components":[
    {
        "id":"uibuilder:fa10894e44b3460c93912198a99e3629",
        "component":{
            "name":"Hero",
            "properties":{
                "imageUrl":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532298229144-0ec0c57515c7?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2000&q=80",
                "caption1":"Faucet Collection",
                "caption2":"",
                "buttonText":"Click Me!"
            }
        },
        "componentStyle":{
            "large":{
                "display":"flex",
                "flexDirection":"column",
                "position":"relative",
                "flexShrink":"0",
                "boxSizing":"border-box",
                "marginTop":"10px",
                "minHeight":"10px",
                "minWidth":"10px",
                "overflow":"hidden"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id":"uibuilder:8818c12fe5c94b25c94b23fec033fec7",
        "component":{
            "name":"Text New",
            "properties":{
                "imageUrl":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532298229144-0ec0c57515c7?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2000&q=80",
                "caption1":"New Collection",
                "caption2":"About this collection",
                "buttonText":"Click Me!"
            }
        },
        "componentStyle":{
            "large":{
                "display":"flex",
                "flexDirection":"column",
                "position":"relative",
                "flexShrink":"0",
                "boxSizing":"border-box",
                "marginTop":"50px",
                "minHeight":"50px",
                "minWidth":"50px",
                "overflow":"hidden"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

When compared Json A has 3 child for components & Json B has 2 child for components,
2 components id's from Json B match with 2 components id's of Json A,

Expected output Json Array should be like below , 2nd child from Json A components should retain as is

Expected output

```
{
"components":[
    {
        "id":"uibuilder:fa10894e44b3460c93912198a99e3629",
        "component":{
            "name":"Hero",
            "properties":{
                "imageUrl":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532298229144-0ec0c57515c7?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2000&q=80",
                "caption1":"Faucet Collection",
                "caption2":"",
                "buttonText":"Click Me!"
            }
        },
        "componentStyle":{
            "large":{
                "display":"flex",
                "flexDirection":"column",
                "position":"relative",
                "flexShrink":"0",
                "boxSizing":"border-box",
                "marginTop":"10px",
                "minHeight":"10px",
                "minWidth":"10px",
                "overflow":"hidden"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id":"uibuilder:8818c12fe5c94b27b7f7033fec7910b6",
        "component":{
            "name":"Text",
            "properties":{
                "text":"<p>This iss text</p>"
            }
        },
        "componentStyle":{
            "large":{
                "display":"flex",
                "flexDirection":"column",
                "position":"relative",
                "flexShrink":"0",
                "boxSizing":"border-box",
                "marginTop":"20px",
                "minHeight":"20px",
                "minWidth":"20px",
                "overflow":"hidden"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id":"uibuilder:8818c12fe5c94b25c94b23fec033fec7",
        "component":{
            "name":"Text New",
            "properties":{
                "imageUrl":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532298229144-0ec0c57515c7?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2000&q=80",
                "caption1":"New Collection",
                "caption2":"About this collection",
                "buttonText":"Click Me!"
            }
        },
        "componentStyle":{
            "large":{
                "display":"flex",
                "flexDirection":"column",
                "position":"relative",
                "flexShrink":"0",
                "boxSizing":"border-box",
                "marginTop":"50px",
                "minHeight":"50px",
                "minWidth":"50px",
                "overflow":"hidden"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? ;)

Comment: You need to add any item which is extra in B should be added to JSON A and JSON A retains all the values in JSON A and matching valued from JSON B?

Comment: @Apoorva Chikara Json A is my source data and any changes to components in Json A will not be update to JsonA, instead it will be stored in Json B with the component id refernce from Json A, While building the output i need to get the property values from Json B into Json A for the Component Id;s which match, --- This what required as of now,

Comment: @Sebastian Kaczmarek , so far tried multiple suggestion and now i am no where near the solution that am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```js
const jsonA = {components: [{id: 'uibuilder:fa10894e44b3460c93912198a99e3629',component: {name: 'Hero',properties: {imageUrl:'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532298229144-0ec0c57515c7?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2000&q=80',caption1: 'New Collection',caption2: 'About this collection',buttonText: 'Click Me!',},},componentStyle: {large: {display: 'flex',flexDirection: 'column',position: 'relative',flexShrink: '0',boxSizing: 'border-box',marginTop: '20px',minHeight: '20px',minWidth: '20px',overflow: 'hidden',},},},{id: 'uibuilder:8818c12fe5c94b27b7f7033fec7910b6',component: {name: 'Text',properties: {text: '<p>This iss text</p>',},},componentStyle: {large: {display: 'flex',flexDirection: 'column',position: 'relative',flexShrink: '0',boxSizing: 'border-box',marginTop: '20px',minHeight: '20px',minWidth: '20px',overflow: 'hidden',},},},{id: 'uibuilder:8818c12fe5c94b25c94b23fec033fec7',component: {name: 'Text New',properties: {text: '<b>Component heading</b>',},},componentStyle: {large: {display: 'flex',flexDirection: 'column',position: 'relative',flexShrink: '0',boxSizing: 'border-box',marginTop: '10px',minHeight: '10px',minWidth: '10px',overflow: 'hidden',},},},],};
const jsonB = {components: [{id: 'uibuilder:fa10894e44b3460c93912198a99e3629',component: {name: 'Hero',properties: {imageUrl:'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532298229144-0ec0c57515c7?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2000&q=80',caption1: 'Faucet Collection',caption2: '',buttonText: 'Click Me!',},},componentStyle: {large: {display: 'flex',flexDirection: 'column',position: 'relative',flexShrink: '0',boxSizing: 'border-box',marginTop: '10px',minHeight: '10px',minWidth: '10px',overflow: 'hidden',},},},{id: 'uibuilder:8818c12fe5c94b25c94b23fec033fec7',component: {name: 'Text New',properties: {imageUrl:'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532298229144-0ec0c57515c7?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2000&q=80',caption1: 'New Collection',caption2: 'About this collection',buttonText: 'Click Me!',},},componentStyle: {large: {display: 'flex',flexDirection: 'column',position: 'relative',flexShrink: '0',boxSizing: 'border-box',marginTop: '50px',minHeight: '50px',minWidth: '50px',overflow: 'hidden',},},},],};

const result = jsonA.components.map(ac => ({
  ...ac, 
  ...jsonB.components.find(bc => ac.id === bc.id)
}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This solution will merge the but do not add the if there is a new object which is not in JsonA

Answer (score 1):

```js
const jsonA = { components: [{ id: 'a' }, { id: 'b', test: 'a' }] }
const jsonB = { components: [{ id: 'b', test: 'b' }, { id: 'c' }] }

const combined = { components: jsonA.components }

for (const itemB of jsonB.components) {
  // Check if a has the item
  const indexInA = jsonA.components.findIndex((itemA) => itemA.id === itemB.id)
  // Not in A? Lets add it 
  if (indexInA === -1) combined.components.push(itemB)
  // It exists? Let's replace it
  else combined.components.splice(indexInA, 1, itemB)
}

// {"components":[{"id":"a"},{"id":"b","test":"b"},{"id":"c"}]}
console.log(combined)
```

Comment: This solution will merge and also add new object which exist in JsonB and not in JsonA